# How to delete data in SimpleModal each time a modal window is closed

Tags: jquery, css, simplemodal

I am using Eric Martin's SimpleModal plugin 1.4.1 with JQuery 1.4.2 to display basic form in a modal window.

The form has 2 JQuery UI Datpicker elements.

Everything works as intended (I think).  The Datepickers display their calendars when the user gives focus the the Datepicker textboxes.  When the user clicks the Cancel button, the modal disappears and the values held in the Datepicker elements are hidden.  Here is where the problem lies.

I need the modal window to "forget" all the form values it contains whenever the window is closed either because the form was submitted or the cancel button was clicked, not just hide them.  I don't mind if I have to do this programmatically if necessary.

My current SimpleModal code looks like this:

```
$('#NewDeliverable').click( function() {
            $("#DeliverableFormContainer").modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
                dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                    dialog.data.hide();
                    dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                        dialog.data.slideDown('slow');
                    });
                });
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to @Josiah Ruddell for his help.  Here is the complete working code for anyone else with this issue:

```
$('#NewDeliverable').click( function() 
        {
            $("#DeliverableFormContainer").modal({ 
                onOpen: function (dialog) 
                {
                    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () 
                    {
                        dialog.data.hide();
                        dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () 
                        {
                            dialog.data.slideDown('slow');
                        });
                    });
                },
                onClose: function(dialog)
                {
                    dialog.data.find(':input').each(function () 
                    {
                        switch (this.type) 
                        {
                            case 'password':
                                $(this).val('');
                                break;
                            case 'select-multiple':
                            case 'select-one':
                                $(this).val(-1);
                                break;
                            case 'text':
                            case 'textarea':
                                $(this).val('');
                                break;
                            case 'checkbox':
                            case 'radio':
                                this.checked = false;
                        }
                    });

                    $.modal.close(); // must call this!

                }, persist: true
            });
        });


            }});
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an onclose callback that clears out the modal data. You could easily make this a jquery plugin called clear form.

```
$("#DeliverableFormContainer").modal({
    persist: true, // don't clone the data
    onOpen: function (){ /* code */ },
    onClose: function(dialog){
        dialog.data.find(':input').each(function () {
            if(this.type.match(/password|text|textarea/))
                $(this).val('');
            else if(this.type.match(/select\-multiple|select\-one/))
                $(this).val('-1');
            else if(this.type.match(/checkbox|radio/))
                this.checked = false;
        });
        $.modal.close(); // must call this!
    }
});
```

Comment: Either way should work, I updated the example. You can view edits and pull that code if you prefer.

Comment: The close button is still broken for me.  I'm currently binding by giving the button a class="simplemodal-close" value.  Do I need to do something different?  Also, the Datepickers are popping up still when they gain focus, but the selected value is not injected into the text field when a date selection is made.

Comment: class="simplemodal-close" should work, check for errors somewhere else on the page. The datepicker problem is probably because you are attaching the date pickers to elements before the modal is opened. Then the modal opens and clones those elements. You need to use the option persist: true so simple modal does not clone the data.

Comment: Yep, persist=true fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: If there are multiple modal containers on the same page, should the $.modal.close() command be changed to reference the particular modal container, i.e. $('#DeliverableFormContainer').modal.close()

Comment: From the last time I used his plugin the $.modal was a global instance, and any time you created a new instance it would close the global instance (ie there can only be one instance at a time).